# Modify Karate Output in Gitlab

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, karate

I am using Karate for automation test and leveraging Gitlab CI/CD pipeline to run in the different pipelines. Is it possible to edit the output in the gitlab console?

Right now, when the karate test run in the pipeline the output is typical maven downloading dependencies.

I would like the output to display the karate test scenarios and showing green/red for pass/fail test.

Answer (score 1):

Normally teams never rely on the console log. They use the HTML reports: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

This is the way to go especially when you run test-suites in parallel because the logs will be interspersed.

That said, you should be able to write a small amount of custom code to dump the [`Results`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-4-parallel-execution) object on to the console any way you want.

The downloading of Maven artifacts is normal for a CI build. After that, if your log-level is `DEBUG` you will see a summary of each test, including passed / failed information. You can check if GitLab supports being able to "cache" the Maven dependencies, so you won't see it all the time.